# Converting a hex (two's complement) to Java value

Tags: java, integer, twos-complement

I have this hex value: C9E5249A which is representing a Twos Complement signed 32-bit 
integer representation in C.
How can I get its Java counterpart ?

Comment: Do you have a hex value, or do you have a bunch of 1's and 0's?

Comment: Actual hex value of C9E5249A.

Comment: What is the numeric value in C which you get from this hex value?

Comment: This has nothing at all to do with C. Even if you think so.

Comment: I found this site: http://www.rapidtables.com/convert/number/hex-to-decimal.htm which for the input C9E5249A gives 
Hex    = C9E5249A
Decimal= 12×16⁷+9×16⁶+14×16⁵+5×16⁴+2×16³+4×16²+9×16¹+10×16⁰ = 3387237530
Signed decimal = -907729766
Binary = 11001001111001010010010010011010

My question would now be ... how can I also get that signed decimal ?

Answer (score 1):

You can just call this:

`Integer.parseInt("C9E5249A", 16)`

or actually ...

`Long.parseLong("C9E5249A", 16)`

(because as others noted this hex value you have is too large for the `int` type).

Comment: I tried that ... it gives me this:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "C9E5249A"
 at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
 at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:495)
 at HelloWorld.main(HelloWorld.java:4)

Comment: The mention of 2's complement leads me to believe he may really have 1's and 0's rather than the actual hex value in the Java program.

Comment: @Sergiu Because the "integer" represented by the hex value cannot fit in an integer. You can try `Long.parseLong(hex, 16)`, however I'm not sure what you really want to achieve.

Comment: @Sergiu Then call Long.parseLong in the same way.

Comment: I have to parse some raw data ... and the documentation I got is written for C programmers and I have to write the program in Java.
Long.parseLong(hex, 16) will work but will not yield the correct value ... in the examples I have this should have been a negative value.

Comment: Well... I don't know your exact context. If it's some tricky stuff, you have to be careful and first understand the int/long type differences between C and Java for your particular case. And then rewrite it making sure you don't change the C program logic in any way.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
Long.parseLong("C9E5249A", 16);
```

C9E5249A is too big for Integer.parseInt which parses the string as a signed decimal integer, see API